# Code Coverage report on unit tests for Windows CE code using TFS 2010

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, windows-ce, code-coverage

I have a unique combination of platforms in my solution that has stumped me.

We need to generate code coverage statistics for unit tests that we're writing for our Windows CE code. We're using Visual Studio 2008 to write the CE code, of course, because VS 2010 doesn't support smart devices.

Unfortunately, MSTest won't instrument CE assemblies for collecting coverage data, so we're compiling our test assembly as a regular Win32 library and using it to call the CE code we need to test. This is working fine on a desktop installation of Visual Studio, but we also need to incorporate this into our nightly build on the server.

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work. It's frustrating because I can manually do everything on my workstation, I just can't get TFS 2010 to do it for me automatically.

Is anybody else writing unit tests for Windows CE code? I can't believe I'm the only one!

Thanks in advance for whatever tips or tricks you might be able to offer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing C++ or C# code, our [SD Test Coverage Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage) can be used to instrument your source code in a way that is compatible with embedded devices.  These tools provide automated instrumentation of your source code, and instrumentation data collection procedures in source code so that you can control how the instrumentation data is collected and exactly how it is dumped, which is ideal for embedded software.  A GUI display provides a programmer view of the coverage data imposed on the source code, and an XML report (which you can format at HTML using XSLT) provides summary data.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check it out, on Monday, and see if it looks like it will do the job.

It looks like there's no trial available, so I'll have to see if my client is willing to buy a copy to try it out... so far, you've got the first tool I've seen that works in CE though!

Comment: As a follow up, to anyone else who wonders, we ended up purchasing licenses to several Semantic Designs test coverage tools, and are in the process of incorporating them into our build scripts.